# How to program Telegram bot (using python) to create unique invite links for my telegram channel?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

Telegram now has the new feature of creating unique invite links for channels. These links allow us to track how many people joined using a particular invite link. This is useful if you are running a referral program to see how many people joined using an invite link.

[See image of this new feature in telegram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDTKv.png)

My question is how do I program my telegram bot (using python) to automatically create this unique invite link and send this unique link to any user that interacts/says hi to my bot?